# Oracle sql - join and group by clause to pull out a top customers with most orders

Tags: sql, oracle

edit2: This is what I got :

Tables :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML4uA.jpg

I am trying to pull out a top of 25% of the customers who belong to a company and have the most orders.

I tried below query:

```
Select customer_id,
(
Select Count(order_id) from order 
where commercial_customer.customer_id = order.customer_id
) AS Orders limit by 25/100 * (Count(*) from order) ;
```

but I'm getting

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
>   00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 5 Column: 13

After following the suggestions from comments I got to this query:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mciC7.jpg

It displays everything right but the Orders which is 3 for both because the Count(*) counts all the orders where customer_id=2.

In order to make this work I would use

```
Select customer_id,customer_name,company_code,Orders
from xyz_customer,xyz_commercial, (
Select Count(*) AS Orders from xyz_order
**where customer_id=xyz_comcustomer.customerid**
)
where
rownum<=(select count(*)from XYZ_COMCUSTOMER)/3
```

but I am getting this:

```
ORA-00904: "XYZ_COMCUSTOMER"."CUSTOMERID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 19
```

**Expected result:

Customer_ID, Customer_name,Company_code,Orders

4 Marin 87654321 3

1 Alexa 12345678 1**

Comment: 25% customers (with maximal orders count) (1). OR several customers  total owned 25% of all orders (2). OR customers owned 25% orders for one customer (3) ?

Comment: If there are 8 customers, I should display the top 2 customers who have the most orders and who are also found in the commercial_customer table ( that means they also belong to a company and they are not simple customers )

Comment: 100% = 8 customers total in `customer` table or 8 customers in `commercial_customer` table ?

Comment: Oh seems like Im confusing everybody, sorry for that. There are 12 customers in  (customer) table and there are 8 customers in ( commercial_customer) table. I will edit my original post to make it more clear...

Comment: You actually don't have a master FROM clause.  Your inline view does, but you primary select is not actually selecting FROM anything.  And you can do things in SQL that you have to write large amounts of code to accomplish.

Comment: What about ties, i.e. three of eight customers having the same top amount of orders? Or one top, two second?

Comment: Seeing that the `xyz_customer` table doesn't have an optional `company_id`, but there is a bridge table `xyz_commercial_customer` instead, I gather that a customer can belong to several companies. Is this correct? If not, you should correct your table design. If yes, do we consider the same customer in two records in `xyz_commercial_customer` the same customer in your query or treat them as two different cutomers?

Comment: A customer should only belong to one company, I created the bridge table in order to avoid having null values in xyz_customer... for example if a customer doesn't belong to a company

Comment: @mrwhite NULL values the best solution.

Comment: @mrwhite: Ah, so `xyz_commercial` has a unique constraint on `customerid`. That is okay, but obfuscates the relation and may often lead to more complicated queries. A simple nullable `companyid` column in `xyz_customer` would be preferable.

Comment: @mrwhite: You haven't answered what shall be done in case of ties.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (with analytical functions)

```
select *
 from
 (
   select customer_id, rank() over (order by count_orders) rank_orders
   from
   (
     select customer_id, count(*) count_orders
     from order
     group by cusomer_id
   )
 )
 where rank_orders <= round((select count(*) from order) / 4)
```

Comment: This is a correct approach.  You need to use a windowed function like RANK.

Comment: @TGray Correct ??? `rank (order by count_orders)` numbers distinct counts 1,2,3,.. Counts of customer. And compares with 1/4 count orders.... 12 customers and 1000 orders ... 12 <= 1000/4 ... query return ALL rows !!!

Comment: @Mike I didn't make a qualitative statement about the actual SQL.  My comment was that the RANK function is the correct way to approach this as you really want the top(n) number of results limited by your condition.  The best way to do this is using a windowing function like RANK.  That's all.  That's why I didn't post a solution myself.  Because it would be redundant given the hbourchi post, which may or may not be the solution - it's just the right approach.

Comment: @MIke, my query is not tested since i don't have access to a db at the moment but the query can not return all rows (as you stated) since the sub-sub query, is grouped by cursomer_id..

Comment: @hbourchi I mean all grouped rows.You compare customers count with orders count. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bbb07/2

Comment: Guys I can't use Rank, have to do it using nested queries

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer_id, cnt
  from (
    select customer_id, cnt, ntile(4) over(order by cnt desc) GRP
      from (
        select O.customer_id, count(*) cnt
          from xyz_order O, xyz_commercial_customer CC
         where O.customer_id=CC.customer_id
         group by O.customer_id
      )
  )
 where GRP=1
```

Window function [`ntile(4)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions101.htm) divides customers into 4 groups. group 1 - 1/4 (25%) customers at descending order number of orders.

Or, using only nested querys (Not recommended):

```
select *
  from (
        select O.customer_id, count(*) cnt
          from xyz_order O, xyz_commercial_customer CC
         where O.customer_id=CC.customer_id
         group by O.customer_id
         order by cnt desc
       )
 where rownum<=(select count(*) from xyz_commercial_customer)/4
```

Comment: Another windowing function that will yield results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use count(*) group by customer_id and a subselect

```
select a.customer_id, a.customer_name
from customer a
inner join order b on a.customer_id = b.customer_id
group by a.customer_id, a.customer_name
having count(*) > (select count(*) from order )/4;
```

Comment: If  a.customer_id  stands for  tablename.attribute then what are the words from customer a ( what does that customer word stand for ) and  from order, what does order stand for? are those tablenames? if so why u didnt put them as a, b?  It only seem to show the customer id and name for 1 person without any other details

Comment: Explain better your comment i don't understand

Comment: Here I uploaded a screenshot [https://postimg.org/image/4r12c4htp/ , the tables and the structure is marked with a red rectangle.

Comment: The image not found 404  anyway  ..From customer  a   mean   :  a is the alia for the tablename costuomer so is possible use a reference to this table simply using a.column_name .. eg:    a.customer_id = b.customer_id mean  customer.customer_id = order .customer_id.. But the important things is    ...my answer is right or not?

Comment: unfortunately no, but it gave me a good idea about how to think about it

Comment: You have error or worng result .. in this case  .. show proper  data sample and the expected result  -

Comment: I edited again the main post providing the tables and the expected result and the query I got to using the suggestions in the comments, please have a look...I am thankfull even for what I got so far

Comment: @mrwhite   . i have  looked at you data so .. you have 6 row in xyz_order and you have  the costomer  with id  2 that had 3 order .. and the others orders are for customer  1,3,4 .. one order  each .. then  ..looking at the number of order  only marin (customer 2) had more the 25% of the orders count (3/6)  . when  if you want two rows could be that i don'understand you question correcly ..  (alexa 1 order 1/6  13,333)